# Disable pjax in rails_admin

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

I use the rails_admin gem, and without adding any custom javascript to it, I get `Cannot read property 'push' of undefined` coming from rails_admin's javascript.

```
$.event.props.push('state') // line causing the error
```

Any idea on how to fix this ? It causes my tests to fail.

It look like this could be caused by pjax (from what I read on some SO posts). I tried disabling it using:

```
register_instance_option :pjax? do
  false
end
```

But it fails in:

```
RailsAdmin.config do |config|

end
```

Where am I supposed to add it ?

Any input will be much appreciated !

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you can disable pjax system-wide. But I had a similar problem with my custom action (it used `send_data`). I was able to disable pjax for my custom action like this:

```
member :custom_action do
  pjax { false } # Without "?"
end
```